# CSS Flex 2 row 4 columns

Tags: html, css

I have a footer that I am trying to have 2 rows.  Top row will have 4 columns (all evenly width) First and Fourth Column will have images.  Second and Third content.  Second row spans 100% width.  I have everything correct except for first row fourth column the width is slightly less than the other 3 and I can't center the image of fourth column but I can on first.

I know it is probably something silly that I am missing but I have been staring at it for hours now.

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #fcf8f8;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column1 img {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20%;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 49);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column4 {
  background-color: rgb(214, 26, 26);
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: aliceblue; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column4 img {
  background-color: rgba(239, 234, 234, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20%;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
}

.copywright {
  color: beige;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column1">
        1st Image here and centered (This one is centered)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column2">
        Some Content here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column3">
        Other Content here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column4">
        3rd Image here and centered (This one will not center)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="copywright">
      © 2023 All rights reserved.
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You should add the images as well (use a sample images from the internet with similar width/height), so that we could first reproduce the problem. I tried adding images on first and fourth column but it seems like they're rendered as you wanted.

Comment: Agreed, this looks pretty good to me in its current state.

Comment: Damzaky you were 100% correct I tried a different image and it works just fine.  Not sure what is wrong with the other image but you have saved me from beating my head on the wall thanks for suggestion!!!

Comment: https://codepen.io/torjescu-sergiu/pen/jOvZNme seem to work. yep